# G is open in X iff $\overline{G \cap \bar{A}}=\overline{G \cap A}$ for all $A\subset X$

Tags: general-topology

> It is clear that $\overline{G \cap {A}}\subset \overline{G \cap \bar{A}}$ but not getting how to show the reverse inclusion!

Comment: For the opposite inclusion, you only need to show $G\cap\overline A\subset\overline{G\cap A}$. Does that help?

Comment: So for each $x \in G\cap\overline A$ let $U$ be nbd of $x$ then $U$ intersects $G$ as well as $A$ therefore $U$ will intersect $\overline{G\cap A}$ thus $x$ $\in \overline{G\cap A}$

Comment: Not good enough: It is not true that if $U$ intersects two sets it will intersect their intersection. But note that $G\cap U$ is *also* a neighbourhood of $x$, since $G$ is open. Since $x\in\overline{A}$, therefore $G\cap U$ intersects $A$, i.e., $(G\cap U)\cap A\ne\emptyset$, or rewritten: $U\cap(G\cap A)\ne\emptyset$.

Comment: @ Neera : how to prove that $G$ is open if $\overline{G \cap \bar{A}}=\overline{G \cap A}$ for all $A\subset X$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $x\notin\overline{G\cap A}$. Then there is an open set $U$ that contains $x$ and such that $U\cap\ G\cap A=\emptyset$. If $G$ is an open set, then so is $U\cap G$; hence, $U\cap G\cap \bar A=\emptyset$.

Suppose now that there exists a point $x\in\overline{G\cap\bar A}$ such that $x\notin\overline{G\cap A}$. We shall prove that $G$ is not open. Indeed, there exists an open set $U$ that contains $x$, intersects $G\cap \bar A$ but is disjoints with $G\cap A$. This would be impossible if $G$ were open.